# ActionScript - textfield that shrinks font size

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How can I create in ActionScript a singleline textfield that automatically shrinks the textsize so that whatever string shall be displayed fits within the size of the textfield?

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'd simply create a function that tries various font sizes until the textfield has the required width. Something like this:

```
            public function shrink(textField, requiredWidth) {
                textField.autoSize = "left"
                var tf:* = textField.getTextFormat();
                tf.size = 50;
                textField.setTextFormat(tf);
                while (textField.width > requiredWidth) {
                    tf.size--;
                    textField.setTextFormat(tf);
                }   
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tf = new TextField();
tf.autoSize=TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
```

You've got the autoSize prop to work with.

```
tw = tf.textWidth
```

and you also can get the specific width of only the contents of a textField with textWidth.

Read up on the [textField](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html) class. Flash contains all manner of formatting and control tools.

Comment: Autosize is for the box itself, not the fontsize.